# Eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of an operator defined by a certain integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, eigenvalues, integral-operators, integral-kernel

Let $k :[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \bf{R} $ be a kernel function definded by
$ k(x,y)= (1- max(x,y))^2 .$ Now, let $ L $ be a linear operator defined on $ L^2 [0,1] $  by $$ Lf(x):=\int_0^1 k(x,y)f(y)dy$$. Can we find eigenfunctions and the associated eigenvalues? (I'm looking for eigenfunctions which forms an orthonormal basis. cf. Hilbert-Schmidt Theorem)

Comment: I've edited the title to try to make it more descriptive, but you could probably improve it further. Please don't post questions with titles that don't give any hint as to what the question is about.

Comment: Your operator was a perfectly well defined (compact, self-adjoint) operator on $L^2(0,1)$ before you added these boundary conditions. These aren't helping at all. Quite on the contrary: If you do include them, then you now have a non-closed operator, so probably you'd want to take its closure, which gets you back to the original one.

Comment: I suspect you got confused about the boundary conditions for the *inverse*: this is an unbounded (as it has to be, since $0\in\sigma (L)$) differential operator whose domain is therefore a subspace of $L^2$, and the bc's are part of the description of this domain. They follow from the form of $L$, as given in the original version of the question.

Comment: I probably contributed to the confusion by not thinking it all the way through in the initial version of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The inverse operator is $L^{-1} = 1/2 \cdot (x-1)^{-1} d^2/dx^2 - 1/2 \cdot (x-1)^{-2} d/dx$. Its eigenfunctions are derivatives of Airy functions, $Ai^{\prime } ((2\lambda )^{1/3} (x-1))$, $Bi^{\prime } ((2\lambda )^{1/3} (x-1))$, where $\lambda $ are the corresponding eigenvalues. Without further specification of the space of functions $f$, i.e., boundary conditions, no further restriction is placed on $\lambda $.

EDIT: Spurred by Christian Remling's comments, the boundary conditions and the resulting quantization of eigenvalues can be further specified: Since $k(1,y)=0$, solutions must vanish at $x=1$, implying that we have to combine the Airy function derivatives as $\sqrt{3} Ai^{\prime } ((2\lambda )^{1/3} (x-1)) + Bi^{\prime } ((2\lambda )^{1/3} (x-1))$. The allowed eigenvalues $\lambda $ are then determined by the condition that $-(2\lambda )^{1/3} $ must correspond to one of the extrema of the function $\sqrt{3} Ai^{\prime } + Bi^{\prime } $.

These eigenfunctions of $L^{-1} $ are also the eigenfunctions of $L$, with eigenvalues $1/\lambda $.

Comment: Your sentence starting with "Without further specification ..." is quite confusing (to me, maybe I'm misinterpreting it). It almost sounds as if you're saying that any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ could be an eigenvalue, but of course the original operator $L$ is a well defined (compact, self-adjoint) operator that has some equally well defined spectrum.

Comment: Rather, the appropriate boundary conditions are delivered to us from the form of the kernel: the functions $u=1$ and $v=(1-x)^2$ are in the domain of $L^{-1}$ near the left and right endpoints, respectively. (So we have Neumann boundary conditions $y'(0)=0$ at $x=0$, and at $x=1$ it's more complicated since this endpoint is singular.)

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't try to read the boundary conditions off the kernel, I was expecting them to be stated. But you are right, combined with the statement that we're on $L^2 $, not any boundary behavior is allowed, I didn't follow through on that. OK, it remains to impose the boundary conditions on the given solutions. Thank you!

Comment: just out of curiosity, how did you find this form of the inverse operator?

Comment: $max(x,y)$ exhibits the "active crease" typical of Green's functions at $x=y$. One can write it in terms of step functions, and taking derivatives w.r.t. $x$ generates $\delta $-functions. So I wrote down the first two derivatives of $k$ and cobbled them together with appropriate prefactors such as to leave an isolated $\delta $-function.

Comment: Just for the record, the argument I had in mind (to find the bc's) would start at the other end: If I have a Sturm-Liouville operator, then the kernel of its resolvent will have the form $G(x,y)=u(x)v(y)$ for $x<y$, with $u, v$ solving the ODE $Ly=0$ and $u,v$ satisfying the bc's at $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively. For $x>y$, we have $G(x,y)=u(y)v(x)$. Now Michael made the nice observation that the OP's kernel is of this form, with $u=1$, $v=(1-x)^2$. This gets us to my second comment.

Comment: This discussion raises an interesting question for me: In my way of thinking, the boundary conditions enter crucially at the final step, arguing $Lf = (1/\lambda) LL^{-1} f = (1/\lambda )f$, where the second equality requires an integration by parts (so that $L^{-1} $ acts on $k$, not $f$) that is only unspoiled by boundary terms when $f$ has the right boundary behavior. I don't explicitly invoke Sturm-Liouville theory here, but perhaps ultimately, this argument only applies to Sturm-Liouville problems anyway? That is for a professional functional analyst to decide ... Christian?

Comment: Is there a well-known quick answer to this or is it worth asking this as a question (I mean, is the method I used only applicable to Sturm-Liouville problems or can it be used for a more general class of problems)?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt: Yes, that would be my interpretation of your solution. It works somewhat more generally than just for SL, but the essence of it is that a kernel with this type of product structure (not quite, due to the two cases, but we know what I mean) is the Green function of a second order differential operator, and then we reverse engineer that operator from the kernel. Your recipe seems a bit informal to me by comparison (the bc's are not just something that is tacked on at the end, they are an essential part of $L^{-1}$, describing its domain).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I was being informal - I understand we should be clear about the space of functions we're working on throughout, not just at the end. One can't really call it "$L^{-1} $" before specifying the boundary conditions. I just asked myself at what point does the formalism actually force me to be clear about this, and, not surprisingly, it's the place where I finally assert that $L^{-1} $ and $L$ are fully fledged inverses of each other, in particular, $LL^{-1}=1$.